# Textbox that MUST contain at least set of char with numbers or not

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

i am making a registration form on windows phone 8 one of its fields is username that should contain at least set of char with numbers or not but can not contains numbers only and can not contain special char i can use username.Text.Any(char.IsDigit);`and`username.Text.Any(char.IsLetter);`but how i will validate the number of char and no special char

Comment: Based on my limited experience with Regex, I would do a for() loop and check every character in the array for the requirements... but it can probably be done quicker with Regex (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you question correctly. A user name must follow these rules:

1) Cannot contain any special characters.

2) Must contain both character and numbers (e.g. not number only 123, or chars only boy).

I think the following would work for you:

```
    private bool ValidateUserName(string Name)
    {
        bool temp = false;

        if (Name.All(char.IsLetterOrDigit) && Name.Any(char.IsDigit) && !Name.All(char.IsDigit)) temp = true;

        return temp;
    }
```

The first part of the condition makes sure that there are no special characters, the second part that there is at least on digit, and the last that it isn't all digits. This worked on the following cases for me:

```
        bool isValid = false;

        string userName = "Kevin123";
        isValid = ValidateUserName(userName);  //true
        userName = "kevinrules";  
        isValid = ValidateUserName(userName);  //false
        userName = "kevin!123";
        isValid = ValidateUserName(userName);  //false
        userName = "12345";
        isValid = ValidateUserName(userName);  //false
```

If I misunderstood the rules please let me know.

Comment: OK - then you would take out the middle condition of the if.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at regular expressions.

For matching w/ C# http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcw2f1c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

For help building an expression http://regexlib.com/ is a good starting point.

Comment: Perhaps a comment on the down-vote, how is this not a valid solution, the OP is clearly already in code (judging by the use of Text.Any)

Comment: I don't think this was worth a negative score and was actually my first thought for this question as well, so upvote to bring you to 0 at least.